# Create a marker / crosshair in a CombinedDomainXYPlot

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to show in a CombinedDomainXYPlot a marker. This is not working. I can add the marker for each subplot. But I want to add it for the CombinedDomainXYPlot. Anybody who can tell me something about this issue. I think with the crosshair the behaviour is the same.

This is working example which creates a CombinedDomainXYPlot and tries to add a marker. The marker adding is in `createCombinedChart()`

```
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.annotations.XYTextAnnotation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisLocation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CombinedDomainXYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.IntervalMarker;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.Marker;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StandardXYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

/**
 * A demonstration application showing how to create a combined chart.
 */
public class MarkerDemo2 extends ApplicationFrame {

/**
 * Constructs a new demonstration application.
 *
 * @param title  the frame title.
 */
public MarkerDemo2(String title) {

    super(title);
    JFreeChart chart = createCombinedChart();
    ChartPanel panel = (ChartPanel) createDemoPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
    setContentPane(panel);

}

/**
 * Creates a combined chart.
 *
 * @return The combined chart.
 */
private static JFreeChart createCombinedChart() {

    // create subplot 1...
    XYDataset data1 = createDataset1();
    XYItemRenderer renderer1 = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
    NumberAxis rangeAxis1 = new NumberAxis("Range 1");
    XYPlot subplot1 = new XYPlot(data1, null, rangeAxis1, renderer1);
    subplot1.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);

    // add secondary axis
    subplot1.setDataset(1, createDataset2());
    NumberAxis axis2 = new NumberAxis("Range Axis 2");
    axis2.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
    subplot1.setRangeAxis(1, axis2);
    subplot1.setRangeAxisLocation(1, AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_RIGHT);
    subplot1.setRenderer(1, new StandardXYItemRenderer());
    subplot1.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);

    XYTextAnnotation annotation = new XYTextAnnotation("Hello!", 50.0, 10000.0);
    annotation.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 9));
    annotation.setRotationAngle(Math.PI / 4.0);
    subplot1.addAnnotation(annotation);

    // create subplot 2...
    XYDataset data2 = createDataset2();
    XYItemRenderer renderer2 = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
    NumberAxis rangeAxis2 = new NumberAxis("Range 2");
    rangeAxis2.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
    XYPlot subplot2 = new XYPlot(data2, null, rangeAxis2, renderer2);
    subplot2.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.TOP_OR_LEFT);

    // parent plot...
    CombinedDomainXYPlot plot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(new NumberAxis("Domain"));
    plot.setGap(10.0);

    // add the subplots...
    plot.add(subplot1, 1);
    plot.add(subplot2, 1);
    plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);

    // Add marker
    Marker marker = new IntervalMarker(30, 40);
    plot.addDomainMarker(marker);
    // Working
    // subplot1.addDomainMarker(marker);

    // return a new chart containing the overlaid plot...
    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("CombinedDomainXYPlot Demo",
            JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
    ChartUtilities.applyCurrentTheme(chart);
    return chart;

}

/**
 * Creates a sample dataset.
 *
 * @return Series 1.
 */
private static XYDataset createDataset1() {

    // create dataset 1...
    XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Series 1a");
    series1.add(10.0, 12353.3);
    series1.add(20.0, 13734.4);
    series1.add(30.0, 14525.3);
    series1.add(40.0, 13984.3);
    series1.add(50.0, 12999.4);
    series1.add(60.0, 14274.3);
    series1.add(70.0, 15943.5);
    series1.add(80.0, 14845.3);
    series1.add(90.0, 14645.4);
    series1.add(100.0, 16234.6);
    series1.add(110.0, 17232.3);
    series1.add(120.0, 14232.2);
    series1.add(130.0, 13102.2);
    series1.add(140.0, 14230.2);
    series1.add(150.0, 11235.2);

    XYSeries series1b = new XYSeries("Series 1b");
    series1b.add(10.0, 15000.3);
    series1b.add(20.0, 11000.4);
    series1b.add(30.0, 17000.3);
    series1b.add(40.0, 15000.3);
    series1b.add(50.0, 14000.4);
    series1b.add(60.0, 12000.3);
    series1b.add(70.0, 11000.5);
    series1b.add(80.0, 12000.3);
    series1b.add(90.0, 13000.4);
    series1b.add(100.0, 12000.6);
    series1b.add(110.0, 13000.3);
    series1b.add(120.0, 17000.2);
    series1b.add(130.0, 18000.2);
    series1b.add(140.0, 16000.2);
    series1b.add(150.0, 17000.2);

    XYSeriesCollection collection = new XYSeriesCollection();
    collection.addSeries(series1);
    collection.addSeries(series1b);
    return collection;

}

/**
 * Creates a sample dataset.
 *
 * @return A sample dataset.
 */
private static XYDataset createDataset2() {

    // create dataset 2...
    XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Series 2");

    series2.add(10.0, 6853.2);
    series2.add(20.0, 9642.3);
    series2.add(30.0, 8253.5);
    series2.add(40.0, 5352.3);
    series2.add(50.0, 3532.0);
    series2.add(60.0, 2635.3);
    series2.add(70.0, 3998.2);
    series2.add(80.0, 1943.2);
    series2.add(90.0, 6943.9);
    series2.add(100.0, 7843.2);
    series2.add(105.0, 6495.3);
    series2.add(110.0, 7943.6);
    series2.add(115.0, 8500.7);
    series2.add(120.0, 9595.9);

    return new XYSeriesCollection(series2);

}

/**
 * Creates a panel for the demo (used by SuperDemo.java).
 *
 * @return A panel.
 */
public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
    JFreeChart chart = createCombinedChart();
    ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
    return new ChartPanel(chart);
}

/**
 * Starting point for the demonstration application.
 *
 * @param args  ignored.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MarkerDemo2 demo = new MarkerDemo2(
            "JFreeChart: CombinedDomainXYPlotDemo4.java");
    demo.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
    demo.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: How were you anticipating the annotation appear in the combined plot?

Comment: Why should they not? The methods for adding annotations are there but they seem not to cause an reaction.

Comment: How not Why; Did you, for example, expect the annotation to appear in both plots? I have explained why they are not working below but can't suggest a solution without further information

Comment: Sorry Graham, I have not read your comment carefully enough. I would expect the Marker to appear all over the CombinedPlot, like a transparent sheet which you lay over the total plot. So the marker should appear in the subplots and in the gaps between the plots, too. I will have a look how draw annotations is realized in XYPlot. Probably you have a good idea. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Graham I developed an adjusted version of CombinedDomainXYPlot, which works for me. The result looks like this.

[image: CombinedDomainXYPlot with Marker]

I merged Code from XYPlot and XYLineAndShapeRenderer to achieve this.
Here is the source code.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Composite;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.jfree.chart.annotations.XYAnnotation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CombinedDomainXYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.IntervalMarker;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.Marker;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotRenderingInfo;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotState;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.ValueMarker;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.Range;
import org.jfree.text.TextUtilities;
import org.jfree.ui.GradientPaintTransformer;
import org.jfree.ui.Layer;
import org.jfree.ui.LengthAdjustmentType;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleAnchor;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets;

public class MyCombinedDomainXYPlot extends CombinedDomainXYPlot {

public MyCombinedDomainXYPlot() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MyCombinedDomainXYPlot(ValueAxis domainAxis) {
    super(domainAxis);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics2D g2, Rectangle2D area, Point2D anchor,
        PlotState parentState, PlotRenderingInfo info) {
    super.draw(g2, area, anchor, parentState, info);
    drawDomainMarkers(g2, area, 0, Layer.FOREGROUND);
}

/**
 * Draws the domain markers (if any) for an axis and layer.  This method is
 * typically called from within the draw() method.
 *
 * @param g2  the graphics device.
 * @param dataArea  the data area.
 * @param index  the renderer index.
 * @param layer  the layer (foreground or background).
 */
@Override
protected void drawDomainMarkers(Graphics2D g2, Rectangle2D dataArea,
                                 int index, Layer layer) {

    // check that the renderer has a corresponding dataset (it doesn't
    // matter if the dataset is null)
    if (index >= getDatasetCount()) {
        return;
    }
    Collection markers = getDomainMarkers(index, layer);
    ValueAxis axis = getDomainAxisForDataset(index);
    if (markers != null && axis != null) {
        Iterator iterator = markers.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Marker marker = (Marker) iterator.next();
            drawDomainMarker(g2, marker, dataArea);
        }
    }

}


/**
 * Draws a vertical line on the chart to represent a 'range marker'.
 * 
 * @param g2
 *            the graphics device.
 * @param plot
 *            the plot.
 * @param domainAxis
 *            the domain axis.
 * @param marker
 *            the marker line.
 * @param dataArea
 *            the axis data area.
 */
public void drawDomainMarker(Graphics2D g2, Marker marker, Rectangle2D dataArea) {

        ValueAxis domainAxis = getDomainAxis();
        if (marker instanceof ValueMarker) {
            ValueMarker vm = (ValueMarker) marker;
            double value = vm.getValue();
            Range range = domainAxis.getRange();
            if (!range.contains(value)) {
                return;
            }

            double v = domainAxis.valueToJava2D(value, dataArea,
                    getDomainAxisEdge());

            PlotOrientation orientation = getOrientation();
            Line2D line = null;
            if (orientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL) {
                line = new Line2D.Double(dataArea.getMinX(), v,
                        dataArea.getMaxX(), v);
            } else if (orientation == PlotOrientation.VERTICAL) {
                line = new Line2D.Double(v, dataArea.getMinY(), v,
                        dataArea.getMaxY());
            }

            final Composite originalComposite = g2.getComposite();
            g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                    AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, marker.getAlpha()));
            g2.setPaint(marker.getPaint());
            g2.setStroke(marker.getStroke());
            g2.draw(line);

            String label = marker.getLabel();
            RectangleAnchor anchor = marker.getLabelAnchor();
            if (label != null) {
                Font labelFont = marker.getLabelFont();
                g2.setFont(labelFont);
                g2.setPaint(marker.getLabelPaint());
                Point2D coordinates = calculateDomainMarkerTextAnchorPoint(
                        g2, orientation, dataArea, line.getBounds2D(),
                        marker.getLabelOffset(),
                        LengthAdjustmentType.EXPAND, anchor);
                TextUtilities.drawAlignedString(label, g2,
                        (float) coordinates.getX(),
                        (float) coordinates.getY(),
                        marker.getLabelTextAnchor());
            }
            g2.setComposite(originalComposite);
        } else if (marker instanceof IntervalMarker) {
            IntervalMarker im = (IntervalMarker) marker;
            double start = im.getStartValue();
            double end = im.getEndValue();
            Range range = domainAxis.getRange();
            if (!(range.intersects(start, end))) {
                return;
            }

            double start2d = domainAxis.valueToJava2D(start, dataArea,
                    getDomainAxisEdge());
            double end2d = domainAxis.valueToJava2D(end, dataArea,
                    getDomainAxisEdge());
            double low = Math.min(start2d, end2d);
            double high = Math.max(start2d, end2d);

            PlotOrientation orientation = getOrientation();
            Rectangle2D rect = null;
            if (orientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL) {
                // clip top and bottom bounds to data area
                low = Math.max(low, dataArea.getMinY());
                high = Math.min(high, dataArea.getMaxY());
                rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(dataArea.getMinX(), low,
                        dataArea.getWidth(), high - low);
            } else if (orientation == PlotOrientation.VERTICAL) {
                // clip left and right bounds to data area
                low = Math.max(low, dataArea.getMinX());
                high = Math.min(high, dataArea.getMaxX());
                rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(low, dataArea.getMinY(), high
                        - low, dataArea.getHeight());
            }

            final Composite originalComposite = g2.getComposite();
            g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                    AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, marker.getAlpha()));
            Paint p = marker.getPaint();
            if (p instanceof GradientPaint) {
                GradientPaint gp = (GradientPaint) p;
                GradientPaintTransformer t = im
                        .getGradientPaintTransformer();
                if (t != null) {
                    gp = t.transform(gp, rect);
                }
                g2.setPaint(gp);
            } else {
                g2.setPaint(p);
            }
            g2.fill(rect);

            // now draw the outlines, if visible...
            if (im.getOutlinePaint() != null
                    && im.getOutlineStroke() != null) {
                if (orientation == PlotOrientation.VERTICAL) {
                    Line2D line = new Line2D.Double();
                    double y0 = dataArea.getMinY();
                    double y1 = dataArea.getMaxY();
                    g2.setPaint(im.getOutlinePaint());
                    g2.setStroke(im.getOutlineStroke());
                    if (range.contains(start)) {
                        line.setLine(start2d, y0, start2d, y1);
                        g2.draw(line);
                    }
                    if (range.contains(end)) {
                        line.setLine(end2d, y0, end2d, y1);
                        g2.draw(line);
                    }
                } else { // PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL
                    Line2D line = new Line2D.Double();
                    double x0 = dataArea.getMinX();
                    double x1 = dataArea.getMaxX();
                    g2.setPaint(im.getOutlinePaint());
                    g2.setStroke(im.getOutlineStroke());
                    if (range.contains(start)) {
                        line.setLine(x0, start2d, x1, start2d);
                        g2.draw(line);
                    }
                    if (range.contains(end)) {
                        line.setLine(x0, end2d, x1, end2d);
                        g2.draw(line);
                    }
                }
            }

            String label = marker.getLabel();
            RectangleAnchor anchor = marker.getLabelAnchor();
            if (label != null) {
                Font labelFont = marker.getLabelFont();
                g2.setFont(labelFont);
                g2.setPaint(marker.getLabelPaint());
                Point2D coordinates = calculateDomainMarkerTextAnchorPoint(
                        g2, orientation, dataArea, rect,
                        marker.getLabelOffset(),
                        marker.getLabelOffsetType(), anchor);
                TextUtilities.drawAlignedString(label, g2,
                        (float) coordinates.getX(),
                        (float) coordinates.getY(),
                        marker.getLabelTextAnchor());
            }
            g2.setComposite(originalComposite);

        }
    }




/**
 * Calculates the (x, y) coordinates for drawing a marker label.
 * 
 * @param g2
 *            the graphics device.
 * @param orientation
 *            the plot orientation.
 * @param dataArea
 *            the data area.
 * @param markerArea
 *            the rectangle surrounding the marker area.
 * @param markerOffset
 *            the marker label offset.
 * @param labelOffsetType
 *            the label offset type.
 * @param anchor
 *            the label anchor.
 * 
 * @return The coordinates for drawing the marker label.
 */
protected Point2D calculateDomainMarkerTextAnchorPoint(Graphics2D g2,
        PlotOrientation orientation, Rectangle2D dataArea,
        Rectangle2D markerArea, RectangleInsets markerOffset,
        LengthAdjustmentType labelOffsetType, RectangleAnchor anchor) {

    Rectangle2D anchorRect = null;
    if (orientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL) {
        anchorRect = markerOffset.createAdjustedRectangle(markerArea,
                LengthAdjustmentType.CONTRACT, labelOffsetType);
    } else if (orientation == PlotOrientation.VERTICAL) {
        anchorRect = markerOffset.createAdjustedRectangle(markerArea,
                labelOffsetType, LengthAdjustmentType.CONTRACT);
    }
    return RectangleAnchor.coordinates(anchorRect, anchor);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`drawAnnotations` is implemented in `XYPlot`, unfortunately `CombinedDomainXYPlot` subclasses `XYPlot` but doesn't call `drawAnnotations` in its overridden implementation of `draw` or forward the annotation on to the subplots.

You could possible provide your on implemntation of `addAnnotation` and `removeAnnotation` by subclassing `CombinedDomainXYPlot`.