# How to a add a dynamic Text/String annotation for particular datapoint on line chart in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am looking for a method to add a dynamic `String` annotation on line chart for a particular data point in `JFreeChart`. For an example, refer to the image below.
Now, for the given plot, let's say I want to show a marker (like small triangle symbol) and "Temperature too high" string at particular point when the temperature value crosses 100 C. Then how should I write a `JavaScript` which will allow me to do so? The temperature value will be fixed (i.e. 100 C) but the plot will be different depending upon different experiments (i.e. the location of datapoint will not be fixed and it will get changed since it's based on the experiment).

[image: Temperature vs Time Plot]

Comment: Why use JavaScript? Why not use a `org.jfree.chart.annotations.TextAnnotation`?

Comment: Hi trashgod! Yes, actually I am bit novice to JFreeChart. How do I use org.jfree.chart.annotations.TextAnnotation for the given problem?

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12914179/230513).